# Boostrap Slider inside tabs

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-slider

I have three tabs and inside the tabs a bootstrap slider. But the slider is only working on the active tab and on the other tabs. How can I trigger the slider on the other tabs?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h3>HOME</h3>
  <div class="text-center well well-lg">
  <input type="text" id="poolSlider" value="8" data-slider-value="8"
  data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" 
  data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="before"
  data-slider-tooltip="show">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
 <h3>Menu 1</h3>
  <div class="text-center well well-lg">
    <input type="text" id="poolSlider" value="8" data-slider-value="8"
    data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" 
    data-slider
    orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="before" 
    data-slider-tooltip="show">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
 <h3>Menu 2</h3>
  <div class="text-center well well-lg">
   <input type="text" id="poolSlider" value="8" data-slider-value="8" 
   data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" 
   data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="before"
   data-slider-tooltip="show">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

With this small standard script code:

```
$('#poolSlider').slider({
formatter: function (value) {       
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
}
});
```

I build up the example on fiddle:

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/benny320/xtz9xwbv/6/#&togetherjs=4OFSeMlKOC)

Answer (score 0):

You should use separate ids for the slider controls and select using a class or attribute.

The following should work.

```
$('input[type=text]').slider({
formatter: function (value) {       
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
}
});
```

Comment: thanks now it's working fine. I have edited the fiddle code